# 5.25 Through Parallel Through USB

Tags: linux, usb, drivers, floppy, parallel-port

I have managed to find an old external parallel 5.25" Drive, I have connected this up with a USB to Parallel cable. The cable is detected fine in Linux.

I could spend hours browsing the web and or try to write my own driver for it. My programming skills are intermediate.

I was wondering if anyone here could help point me in the right direction for accessing Parallel drives through USB.

Thanks.

Comment: Try https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com (assuming you mean something like a ZIP drive accessed through the parallel port, etc.)

Comment: Out of curiosity what does the log say when the cable is plugged in?

Answer (score 1):

In old times the PC parallel port was directly mapped into I/O space of PC, with full arbitrary bit/byte access to data and control register of the port. Drivers for various "parallel port" devices as tapes, external floppies etc. would use proprietary bit-wise access to make the interface working. The interface for floppy would likely use certain individual bits and special timing explicitly controlling stepping motor and other oddities which I forgot long time ago. And these drivers would use direct hardware access.

The modern USB to parallel port dongles don't provide the same functionality, they are USB-to-"parallel printer" ports, and provide only limited-functionality of CENTRONIX interface. It is very unlikely that the virtualized USB dongle will be able to drive your old 5.25" drive.